# Is There a Way to Include Markdown in HTML/Websites?

Tags: javascript, html, markdown

I'm currently adding a section to my website and I want to put together a guide on the page for the people that will be looking at this particular section of my site. I'd like to use Markdown for formatting and presentation. Is there any way to this inside of an HTML file?

I've tried using [Strapdown](http://strapdownjs.com) but it only supports certain bootstrap themes and I would like to use my own HTML around the markdown text. I haven't been able to find a StackOverflow post that explains how to do this either.

Comment: If someone could also explain why I got down-voted I'd appreciate that.

Comment: I honestly see this question going unanswered. Find an existing JQuery plugin or better yet a PHP script to pre-process this for you.

Comment: +1. good question. so you want something like strapdown.js which renders the markdown as html while using your own css?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Markdown is not a part of the HTML standard. You need something to parse the markdown "codes". There are plenty of libraries which can do this for you though.

- [Here is Stackoverflow's own parser](https://github.com/jwiegley/markdown.net) (for .NET server side)
- [A parser written in JavaScript](https://github.com/chjj/marked)

and many many more (search is your friend).

Comment: Hmm...didn't know the marked parser supported GFM. That's awesome. Thanks!